# Hyperledger Fabric multichannel multiple chaincode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Is it possible to create a network with two orgs , org1 having two peers p1 and p2 , org2 having peer p3.
P1 and p2 joining channel1 and p1 and p3 in channel2. Channel1 having chaincode1 and channel2 having chaincode2 instantiated. And on a valid condition chaincode1 invoking chaincode2. Will both transaction proposal works?

Answer (score 0):

- InvokeChaincode locally calls the specified chaincode `Invoke` using the
  same transaction context; that is, chaincode calling chaincode doesn't
  create a new transaction message.
- If the called chaincode is on the same channel, it simply adds the called
  chaincode read set and write set to the calling transaction.
- If the called chaincode is on a different channel, only the Response is 
  returned to the calling chaincode; any PutState calls from the called chaincode 
  will not have any effect on the ledger; that is the called chaincode on a 
  different channel will not have its read set and write set applied to the 
  transaction.
- Only the calling chaincode's read set and write set will be applied to the 
  transaction. Effectively the called chaincode on a different channel is a 
  `Query`, which does not participate in state validation checks in subsequent 
  commit phase. If `channel` is empty, the caller's channel is assumed.

---

```
InvokeChaincode(chaincodeName string, args [][]byte, channel string) pb.Response
```

See the shim interface link [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release-1.4/core/chaincode/shim/interfaces.go)